# Asymptotic behavior of European options

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finance, parabolic-pde

In some of the numerical work on Black-Scholes generalized models, the boundary conditions on the truncated domain taken from the asymptotic behaviors of European call options, which are given by
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} u(\tau,x)=0,~\text{and}~\lim_{x \to \infty}u(\tau,x)-K(e^{x-\int_0^\tau D(s)ds}-e^{-\int_0^\tau r(s)ds}),$$
where, $u(\tau,x)$ is the option's value depending on the price variable $x$ and time variable $\tau$ with the strike price $K$. The parameters $r$ and $D$ represents the interest rate and dividend yield, respectively.

My questions are:

1. What precisely the financial importance of these asymptotic behaviors?
2. What type of hedging strategy is being processed at the truncated boundaries in numerical approaches?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it feels like it would get a better answer on https://quant.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I guess $x$ is the ***log moneyness*** $\log(S_0/K)$ where $S_0$ is today's stock price. Then $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}$ corresponds to $\lim\limits_{S_0\to 0}$ and
   $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}$ corresponds to $\lim\limits_{S_0\to+\infty}\,.$ It is clear that in ***any*** model for the dynamics of $S_t$ we must have (abusing notation)
   $$
   \lim_{S_0\to 0}u(\tau,S_0)=0\,
   $$
   because a call option on a stock must be worth zero if the stock goes to zero.
   This is the first boundary condition. For very large $S_0$ (or $x$) we must have in ***any*** model
   \begin{align}
   u(\tau,S_0)&\approx S_0\,e^{-\int_0^\tau D(s)\,ds}-Ke^{-\int_0^\tau r(s)\,ds}\\
   &=K\left(e^{x-\int_0^\tau D(s)\,ds}-e^{-\int_0^\tau r(s)\,ds} \right)\,,
   \end{align}
   because for a very large stock price the call option must approach that difference regardless of the stock volatility, or the dynamics of $S_t$.
   This is the second boundary condition.
2. In a tree or PDE approach you choose a large enough upper boundary at which you apply the second boundary condition. You ignore all values of $S_t$ that are above that boundary. The hedging strategy was only a no arbitrage argument used to derive the pricing equation that you are solving. I don't think you need to worry about the hedging strategy at those boundaries, unless I misunderstood question 2.